# Auto populate fields in a PHP form with a Drop down selection

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm new here and new in php too. So if anyone may help me through this problem, im really appreciate it.

Here's my problem. I already have made a select menu and it function well. But now i want when i click on one of data in the select menu, then it will generate other field to display the data. For example:

```
Database name: "Test"

Table: "Select"

Column 1: "id"

Column 2: "name"

Column 3: "address"
```

For the select menu, i make "id" in it. So i want, when i click on one of the "id", then on field "name" and "address" there will generate the data from that column in it.

So if someone has an example to show it, i really-really appreciate it.

```
<?php
include("mysql_connect.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<form id="daftar" name="daftar" method="post" action="TESTING.php">
  <label for="textfield">Name:</label>
  <select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="0">-- Please select --</option>
<?php 
$getallNew = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new ");
while($viewallNew = mysql_fetch_array($getallNew))
{
?>
<option id="<?php echo $viewallNew['id'];?>"><?php echo $viewallNew['name']; ?>
</option>
<?php 
} 
?>
</select>

</p>
<p>

</p>
<p>
<label for="textfield3">Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" >
</p>
<p>

</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do u tried something?

Comment: I just have done till the select menu only. If you have any  simple example, you may show me. thanks

Comment: i already edit my post with the code. please see it. Thanks. Sorry for late.

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: i cant because i dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need JavaScript for that. Basically:

1. Listen to the `click` event on the `select` menu
2. When clicked: get the selected value (id) and send a request to the server using XHR (Ajax)
3. Process the request on the server with PHP: query the database for the `id` and output a list of names and addresses
4. Append the returned output to your form

jQuery is commonly used to make this easier, for instance [listening for an event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [doing the Ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). There are tons of examples online, too.

Comment: sorry. can you show me an example because i dont understand much about this. thanks.

Comment: [This example](http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/dynamic-select-list-jquery-php/) is quite similar to what you're trying to achieve. You [can Google](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=populate+select+using+ajax+jquery&gws_rd=ssl) to find out lots more on this.

Comment: btw may i ask some question.    
with same code shown above i add search button to the list menu so that when i click on the search button, then the address that associate with the "name" will display. But my problem is how can i make on the "name" field stay with what i choose? because when i click on one of the "name" and click search button, the "address" displayed but on the "name" field it change back to "Please select".

Comment: With Ajax, only update a part of the page (the `select` menu for the address), it seems like you're updating everything, eg. refreshing the whole page.